# Comparing two numbers without loops or branching in Python

Tags: python

I have to compare two numbers and write greater, then smaller, but I don't know how to get smaller one. I currently have this code:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = round(((a + b) + abs(a - b)) / 2)
x = "should be smaller one"
print("{0}\n{1}".format(c, x))
```

Comment: Won't `min(a, b)` work for you?

Comment: We just started using python in school so I'm limited to basic operations

Comment: smaller is : `c = round(((a + b) - abs(a - b)) / 2)`

Comment: Can't use <, > or similiar operations.

Comment: What kind of course prohibits you from using logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smaller is : `c = round(((a + b) - abs(a - b)) / 2)`

Comment: And then the larger one is obviously `d = a + b - c`, for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you:

```
In [1]: a , b = 3, 4

In [2]: smaller = a if a < b else b

In [3]: smaller
Out[3]: 3
```

Here you can replace `<` to other operator